# Error "400 Bad request" when sending JSON object to an api using Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Here is a snippet of code:

```
api_url = {url}
auth_head = {key: value} << my api authentication header
data = {'title':'Python'}  << the valid json object format that the api accepts
```

Here is what I tried:

```
data = json.dumps(data)
json_obj = json.loads(data)
response = requests.post(api_url, headers = auth_head, data = json_obj)
print(response.text)
```

Here is the output:
"400 Bad request"

To make sure the url and my api token key work I tried GET:

```
response = requests.get(api_url, headers = auth_head)
print(response.status_code)
```

Output:
"200"

So the url and api token work fine. I feel I am not sending the correct json object construct that the api wants

Comment: What's the point of doing `json.dumps` followed immediately by `json.loads`? You just get back the object you started with.

Comment: That's true. I tried without json.loads() and also I needed to modify my headers dictionary to add a key: value 'content-type': 'application/json' and then it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send data as `json`. Just send data as dictionary. It will accept. `requests` automatically will encode your dictionary to `json`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. However, I also needed to modify my headers dict. It worked after that :)